# why static need connect <T> in java?

Tags: java

Why do I need to add `<T>` when I declare a generic static method? If I don't the compiler throws an error:

```
//doesn't compile
private static T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<?> it) {}

//compiles
private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<?> it) {}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here. But if you mean, what's the `<T>` for in your second method declaration above, consider: What would the method's return type be if you didn't have it?

Comment: Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The difference is that the object-method uses the type which is most likely defined at class-level. Static methods can't use them

Comment: Because that's how the syntax for generic static methods works?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a method in a generic class like this:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    public void doSomething(T input) {}
}
```

, doSomething belongs to the class, so the compiler knows type T (from the surrounding class).

If you have a static function, it can be in any class, even a non-generic one:

```
class MyClass {
    public static <T> void doSomething(T input) { };
}
```

If you left out the  in this case, the compiler would not be able to tell what type to use.

EDIT:
to be more precise: the compiler would not be able that you are trying to use a generic type and would assume "T" to be the actual name of a class.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<T> it) {

}
```

becouse static generic methods need generic declaration `<T>`, and this declaration will be differ from the class where this method located(as method could be in generic class as well)

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<T> it) {
    }
}

<T> could be different for class and method
```

Answer (score 0):

In non static method you could put definition of generic declaration on class instance. You can't do this for static methods, as they don't need to have instance to execution.